# Image create PHP on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer

I have a strange problem with PHP Images and Webbrowsers..

First of all, I know that PHP is a server-side language and that it has nothing to do with the browser, but WHY THE HELL is my script working with Firefox or Safari or Chrome and not with Internet Explorer??

```
    function image_effect_negative($counter,$file,$layer){


$image = "../images/tmp/$file/layer_$layer.png";


$img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

if($layer == 0){
    $path = "../images/tmp/$file/$counter".".jpg";
}else{
    $path = "../images/tmp/$file/layer_$layer.png";
    $path2 = "../images/tmp/$file/tmp_layer_$layer.png";
}

if($img && imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE)){
    //imagepng($img, $path);

    if($layer > 0)
        imagepng($img, $path2);
    else
        imagejpeg($img,$path);

    imagedestroy($img);

    return $img;
}
```

}

I use the code above, that loads layer_0.png (for example) and uses an imagefilter on it. With every other browser the Image with the effect is created, but not in IE !

What is wrong??

Comment: Try saving the generated PNG in firefox/chrome and then loading that image directly in IE. it could be your image is corrupt/incompatible, and only some browsers are able to open it.

Comment: Why return `$img` at the end? That's an invalid GD handle at that point, since you've done an `imagedestroy()` on it immediately beforehand

Comment: What version of IE? If it's less than 7, it doesn't support alpha-transparent PNG's

Answer (score 1):

What version of Internet Explorer are you using? Older versions of IE are known to not work with transparency types such as pngs. Try adding PNG fixer to your page for IE and see if that fixes it. You can find PNG fixer here:

http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I know that already! The problem is not displaying the image, but creating it!

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to return when you destroy the image before that?

```
  imagedestroy($img);    // why are you destroying the image?

  return $img;
}
```

Also, have you set the correct header to return an image to the browser?

Comment: Sorry, the return $img was just for some pre-testing, forget about that! I do not want to display the image to the browser, but saving it fo a file!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you aren't generating HTTP headers. Some browsers are able to detect whether `http://example.com/foo.php` contains a PNG or JPEG files, other browsers are not. It's as simple as:

```
if($layer > 0){
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($img, $path2);
}
else{
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($img,$path);
}
```